# Recieving this error "node_modules/@types/node/assert.d.ts(8,68): error TS1144: '{' or ';' expected."

Tags: selenium, protractor

While running gulp e2e-ci-test  I recieving TS1144 error
"devDependencies": {

```
    "@types/chai": "^3.5.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.29",
    "@types/jasmine-ajax": "^3.1.27",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.26",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0"
}
```

These are my dependencies

Comment: pkease add the code or package.json

Comment: {
        "typescript": "^4.2.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@syncfusion/ej2-build": "*",
        "@types/chai": "^3.5.2",
        "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.29",
        "@types/jasmine-ajax": "^3.1.27",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
        "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.26",
        "chai": "^4.3.4",
        "protractor": "^7.0.0"
    }
}
@PDHide I have deleted the node modules and Package.lock and run npm i .I got a new error"error TS2304: Cannot find name 'globalThis'."